# Bootstrap tooltip - tooltip function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the tooltips in Bootstrap so that when the user mouseovers a link, the text appears. You can see how it should look here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Instead, nothing happens when I mouseover my links. Here's my HTML:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="test" class="quoteform"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip-left toollink" data-original-title="This text should appear in a tooltip."><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>Test<span aria-required="true" class="required">* <span></span></span></label>
                    <select class="form-control quotedetails" id="test">
                        <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Here's the JS I'm running in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tip-top").tooltip({
            placement : 'top'
        });
        $(".tip-right").tooltip({
            placement : 'right'
        });
        $(".tip-bottom").tooltip({
            placement : 'bottom'
        });
        $(".tip-left").tooltip({
            placement : 'left'
        });
    });
```

When I run the page, I get this error: TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function. I thought this might be because I had incorrectly linked to jquery and bootstrap.min.js, but I can navigate to both of them and they look fine. Additionally, I tried replacing both of them with links to their respective CDN's but it made no difference.

Here are the JS files I'm linking to:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/plugins/jquery.1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/sticky-tabs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/jquery.select2list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you included the `bootstrap.js` file?

Comment: most common reason is wrong order of include js files or wrong path, especially if you work in a cms that changes paths.

Comment: Did you include the `tooltip.js` file.

Comment: Isn't tooltip.js part of bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: I tried your code in a fiddle and its working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y82jaux3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add JS for tooltip

https://jsfiddle.net/Skaadel/ewscg13g/

Tooltip JS

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Comment: Added your html / js into my page to test, and got the same error again - TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function. Not sure what's causing this since I tried both my local versions of jquery / bootstrap.min.js and the CDN versions

Comment: Where do you want the tooltip exacly? On the links in the dropdown?

Comment: To the left of the label for the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you did not add tooltip.js . It's an additional plugin that you need to include.

Answer (score 0):

i think you haven't included js and css properly coz here it's working fine for me in jsfiddle.

and here is the demo working example

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<div class="tooltipss">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vquawkh0/2/) and all I had to change was `.tip-left` to `.tip-bottom`. Somehow the tooltip wasn't visible on the left side. I suggest you try removing scripts, which are not needed for your tooltip to work (anything other than jquery, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css and font-awesome.min.css), as bootstrap doesn't work well with other jquery plugins like jquery-ui etc.